# function to print uint16_t var to 4 places will not work

Tags: c, arduino, char

platform: ESP8266 and Arduino

I am trying to output an `uint16_t` in a 4 char places.  The laser(VL53L0X) is getting reading from 2 to 4 number places.(will never go over 4 places, MAX 8190 out)

```
Serial.print( mmLaser);
```

works but cannot format the 4 places.
if I call the function I get an error

```
**ERROR:** invalid conversion from 'char' to 'char*' [-fpermissive]
```

if I compile without calling the function: no errors

What am I doing wrong?

**Declared Vars**

```
char  c_temp;
uint16_t mmLaser = 0;  // hold laser reading
```

**function called**

```
uint16_2_char( mmLaser, c_temp); 
Serial.print( c_temp );
```

**Function**

```
// Convert uint16_t to char*
// param 1 n - uint16_t Number
// param 2 c - char to return char value to
//
void uint16_2_char(uint16_t n, char* c){
    sprintf( c, "%04d", (int) n );
}
```

Comment: What does your compiler have to say about passing a `char` to a function expecting a `char *`?

Comment: `char  c_temp;` --> `char  c_temp[100];`  Guess I do not trust the _never_ in "will never go over 4 places".  Better to right size the buffer to the maximum an `int` would produce.

Comment: I find myself oddly disconcerted that I'm pointing out that unsigned ints *do not have decimal places*.  It doesn't help that this is an odd jigsaw puzzle of a question.  Please read [ask].  Take it to heart.  Provide an [mcve]

Comment: the 4 place limit is set because the laser readings(millimeters) max at 8190 and with the laser covered the smallest is 18 -- you are correct they are whole numbers NOT decimals

Comment: `"%04d"` is _not_ a maximal limit.  `4` is a _minimum_ limit of the width of characters that will be "printed" to the string.  That will need _at least_ 5 `char`.  Depending on the platform and the future, the function _as coded_, make need 7 `char`.  Why risk buffer overflow?, Be generous in buffer allocation.

Answer (score 1):

Code needs an array of characters

```
//       Pointer to a character -----v                            
void uint16_2_char(uint16_t n, char* c){
  sprintf( c, "%04d", (int) n );
}
```

Problem code

```
//     This is one character
char  c_temp;

uint16_t mmLaser = 0;  // hold laser reading

// **ERROR:** invalid conversion from 'char' to 'char*'
// Does not make sense to pass a character when an address is needed
// Need to pass the initial _address_ as an array of characters instead.
//                         v
uint16_2_char( mmLaser, c_temp);
```

Better code

```
#define INT_BUF_SIZE 24 
char buffer[INT_BUF_SIZE]; 

// When an array is passed to a function, 
// it is converted to the address of the 1st character of the array.
//  The function receives &buffer[0]
uint16_2_char( mmLaser, buffer);
```

Even better, pass an address and the size available

```
void uint16_2_char(uint16_t n, char* c, size_t sz){
  unsigned u = n;
  // I'd expect using unsigned types.  (use `%u`)
  // snprintf() will not not overfill the buffer
  snprintf( c, sz, "%04u", u);
}

char buffer2[INT_BUF_SIZE]; 
uint16_2_char2( mmLaser, buffer, sizeof buffer);
```